# Laravel 5 shows blank page on server but works locally

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, nginx

I'm having an issue since today when I uploaded updates to my production server from my local development environment on my laptop.

When I try to access a page, it's completely blank. I didn't touch anything - I did like I always do when uploading new files, which has always worked.

**I can also access my assets, like images, js and css perfectly fine. And my auth middleware is working as I'm using Steam login and it redirects me to login through Steam.**

What I remember doing before it broke:

- Uploaded my files
- ran `composer dumpautoload`
- ran `php artisan cache:clear`

What I have done so far:

- Checked my NGINX/PHP/MySQL error logs. Nothing.
- Checked laravel logs, nothing there either.
- Made sure PHP, NGINX and Mysql is running.
- Made sure php, nginx and mysql is up to date.
- Generated a new key
- Double checked my .env so it's valid.
- composer update
- chmodded my directories (even though I had no problems with this prior to the blank page).

At this point I don't know how and why it suddenly does not work, when it's working perfectly fine on my local laptop.

nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name example.com;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;

    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

    root /var/www/preview/example/public;

    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff";

    charset utf-8;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;

        #auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        #auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }

    location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
        deny all;
    }

    server_name hsbuilds.com;
    ssl    on;
    ssl_certificate /home/hsbuilds/src/hsbuilds/example.com.chained.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/hsbuilds/src/example.com/example.com.key;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

    #location / {
    #   proxy_pass http://example.com:8000;
    #   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    #}
}
```

Edit: When checking the network tab in chrome, the page returns code 200.

Comment: if you don't get any error it sounds like an error (unwanted character) in your .env file. Laravel quits with a 500 but no error if the .env is invalid

Comment: Check the logs in `storage/logs` to see if there's any exception happening.

Comment: There are no errors going on there @solarc and I never touched my .env file with the update as it worked before that (but I've verified it's valid)

Comment: Are there nginx logs?

Comment: Have you tried setting `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` to see any warnings/errors?

Comment: @kerbholz yes and it's still just a blank page. And no there are no logs anywhere.

Comment: There might be no logs because the error is that the storage/logs folder is not writeable. Also check that your php configuration doesn't suppress errors. Make also sure that you have set an the .env APP_KEY variable, if not run: `php artisan key:generate`

Comment: It is writable, I can make errors in my auth controller (which it can see) and it'll report that. But otherwise there's nothing, and PHP isn't supressing it either.

Comment: My guess is still .env. Any character at the begining or end? Laravel normally logs errors - only if the .env file is not ok it won't...

Comment: The APP_KEY is set. I've generated it twice now to no avail.

Comment: @jtwes https://pastebin.com/xzsctGk0 Here's my .env with all sensitive data removed.

Comment: Which page/url/route is the one being blank? Can you post the source code or relevant parts of the controller that is causing the blank page? Which file have you overwritten/created with your last upload?

Comment: All routes are blank (but assets work, like css and js). I only overwrote some view files and one controller. But as I said it's fine on my laptop, just not on my production server. @mdexp

Comment: hm. looks okay. I really don't know... Then it can only something on the server config because .env and server config should only differ from your local machine...

Comment: Did you activate laravels maintainance Mode accidentally with php artisan down?

Comment: you could try: rm vendor/composer/autoload_*  and after that composer dumpautoload

Comment: do you get any output on php artisan (list of commands)

Comment: what happens if you use php artisan:tinker

Comment: `php artisan works` but `php artisan:tinker` asks for an input file and I don't know how that works. Maintenance mode is off. I also tried the `rm vendor/composer/autoload_*` and even after `composer dumpautoload` it still does not work.

Comment: sorry - i meant php artisan tinker (without :)

Comment: Did you asign the correct user ? Webserver is using www-Data, so this User needs to own the directory. Maybe you pulled the current version with the wring user

Answer (score 0):

first, check `.env` file and especially vars `APP_KEY`(php artisan key:generate) and `APP_URL`.

Then run, just for sure `php artisan cache:clear && php artisan config:clear && php artisan config:cache`.

Comment: I did all this again just to double check, it didn't help.

Comment: are you using docker ?

Comment: also after env is valid - run composer update. And in case of docker - check logs in docker's apache (nginx)

Comment: No I'm not using docker. I've also run composer update which didn't help sadly. And all logs are empty.

Comment: No ideas for now - any errors anywhere (is the server valid ?), but looks like the reason to switch to docker :)

Comment: it doesn't work even if call `die('123');` at the top of `public/index.php` ?

Comment: There are no logs anywhere, not even in my access log. And `die('123')` works.

Comment: so the reason is in laravel - 100%, not in server ! check .env file according to doc: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example

Comment: I tried using the example and only putting in the crucial info like DB etc and it's still blank.

Comment: APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:gY+JzOF03G01raa+Rjq7qIlYeRx/7bLuJZr1QH8jXb8=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

Comment: these vars are very impotrant, not just db - set them, then clear cache, then update composer (update - not dumpautoload)

Comment: Even after all of that, it's still blank! :(

Comment: so then try to debug the app by adding `die(;123;);` deeper each time - you'll find the issue finally